# How to isolate local backups on Linux from ransomware

Tags: linux, backup

I use local encrypted backup feature of [Backintime](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime) on debian 8.3 to backup my files to an external drive. It automatically backups every 30 minutes. My external drive is always connected. I am the only user of this computer.

Recently I often hear about ransom-ware nightmare [stories](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/03/first-mac-targeting-ransomware-hits-transmission-users-researchers-say/). As my backup location is always accessible, I am thinking about a way to to make my backup location safe and isolated from such attacks, as a precaution.

I thought if I run Backintime as a special "backup user" or root and use a backup location on which only "backup user" or root has write access, I would achieve this. I guess it is advisable to use root only when it is inevitable, so I think I'd prefer to create a "backup user" for this job.

I wonder if I can use file permissions for this purpose or is there a better way.

My questions:

1. Is this a good idea to make my backup location safe?
2. How can I run Backintime automatically as "backup user" while I use the computer with a different account at the same time?
3. How can I assign "backup user" as the only user which has write access on my backup location?

Comment: "My external drive is always connected." - If a volume is connected then it can be encrypted by ransomware, unless you are willing not to have the external always connected, then you cannot protect yourself from ransomware.

Comment: How ransomware can encrypt external drive if current user does not have write access to the external drive, or, to the backup folder in that drive?

Answer (score 1):

1. Store your backups on media that is not physically connected or normally turned on.
2. Have multiple backup media (drives/tapes) that are rotated out on a regular basis.  Bonus points for storing them off-site (at least a few miles/kilometers away).  I recommend a minimum of (3) drives/tapes, with only 1 or 2 units of the set being kept onsite.
3. Permissions to write or access the backup directory should be limited to the root account.
4. Your day-to-day user account should not have `sudo` permissions.  Use a second user-level account to do system administration via `sudo`.  If you don't have the ability to elevate privileges, then you can't be tricked into elevating privileges.
5. Dismount the backup directory when not in use using tools like `autofs`.  That also gives the advantage that you can unplug the drive without worrying about whether the file system is mounted.  The `autofs` tool can be configured to auto-mount the backup directory, then dismount it after a few minutes of inactivity.
6. Use a backup tool that is efficient at storing lots and lots of incrementals ([Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/h), [borg-backup](https://github.com/borgbackup/borg)).  That will let you keep a year's worth of backups on each drive, giving you more possibilities to restore things to how they were prior to the event.